# Simple Phrases in Japanese

Tags: set-phrases

I was experimenting with these phrases to check if they could be used in a normal, everyday conversation in Japanese.

Do these phrases  make sense?

Yoroshiku. (Nice to meet you.)

Yoroshiku onegai itashimasu. (It's a pleasure to make your acquaintance.)

Watashi no namae wa Angela desu.

Watashi wa Angela iimasu.

Watshi wa Angela desu.

Also, if any of these phrases are correct, could anyone transcribe them into kanji?

Answer (score 1):

Your expressions are right, except that in the last sentence, you have to put a *to* before the *iimasu*.

Deromanized versions of them are:

> よろしく。
>
> よろしくお願いいたします。
>
> 私の名前はアンジェラです。
>
> 私はアンジェラといいます。

**[edit]**

In business conversations you should say:

> よろしくお願いいたします。私は(your surname)と[申]{もう}します。

Outside of business, you may use less polite forms:

> よろしくお願いします。私はアンジェラといいます。

A more non-polite, friendly expression is something like:

> よろしく。アンジェラです。

The last one is used on occasions like talking to a new friend who is not older than you. Since few women use this style in Japan, it may sound faily "boyish" when used by a woman.

In all cases, you can drop 私は, and actually it will make them sound more natural.

Comment: I edited my post in reply to your comment. > Questioner